# Android resource compilation failed (cache file error )

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

i'm not able to build my project anymore and I'm getting some error regarding one of the catch files and specifically it takes me to a value called:layoutCron

i took some screenshots to the build console to show the error that happens when trying to build the project...

1-
[image]

2- 
[image]

3- 
[image]

4-
[image]

5-
[image]

when i try to go any further and find the file that they gave me it's path i find this :

[image]

the gradle version i'm using is 4.9 ...
with this  in the project build gradle :

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Three steps to resolve the problem**

- Use a more stable gradle version as 4.4-all
- Update Android Support Plugin version to 3.1.4
- Rebuild Project

`gradle-wrapper.properties` file content:

```
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Top-level build file: dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Finally to show the effect clear gradle cache using `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`

after doing that you won't have any problem in the build part

**NOTE :**
if android studio regenerated the files and gave you the same error afterwards you can just disable Aapt2 but that will only work till the end of 2018

you do that by adding android.enableAapt2=false
 to the gradle.properties file .

Comment: i did what you said but it did not fix the problem ...(Same output)

Comment: Could I can see your gradle dependencies?

Comment: your answer worked to fix that error but i needed to clear the cache after doing your steps...(please add it to the answer and i will accept your answer :) )...

Comment: hey 
this  fixes the problem when building the project but when i run it , android studio regenerates the cache app and gives me the same error again , what should i do to get out of this loop ...

do you still need me to show you my dependencies ?!? i can share my gradle files with you if you need them to help :)

Comment: OK Send its with screenshot after click button who below Make project button in Build panel

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hr9b2Vu5HFKqKgdyNI1FWfDDLFesO5LM?usp=sharing

i added the project gradle and the module gradle in this link

Comment: i'll retake the screenshots after building the project and after trying to run the project as well ... in a minute

Comment: i added the screenshots you asked for to the same link